# New to pandas, I would like to merge 2 rows into 1 if values of columns match

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading in data from a .csv which prints into a table like below.

| Name | R0 | Rm | R1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| B | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| C | 3 | 7 | 10 |
| D | 4 | 8 | 12 |

I want to go consecutively through the specific columns of each row in the DataFrame and if the leading value of Rm is equivalent to Rm of the next row, then I will merge the 2 rows keeping values as presented below, note this is a sample dataframe I am using, the data I am working with contains more rows and columns and I will be using this method for multiple columns.
I have been able to do this for a single row but I have been unable to go down each row comparing and merging.

| Name | R0 | Rm | R1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A,B | 5 | 1 | 3 |
| C | 3 | 7 | 10 |
| D | 4 | 8 | 12 |

Now when I work this into my program, should I attempt to have both column conditions working at the same time or should I loop through the data once for each set of conditions?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid iterating over rows, it is slow.

Instead, you could use `groupby` and `agg`:

```
(df.groupby(df['Rm'].ne(df['Rm'].shift()).cumsum(), as_index=False)
   .agg({'Name': ','.join, 'R0':'max', 'Rm': 'first', 'R1': 'max'})
  )
```

Output:

```
  Name  R0  Rm  R1
0  A,B   5   1   3
1    C   3   7  10
2    D   4   8  12
```